# Delphi FMX Unable to change the drop down text of a TCombobox TListItem at runtime

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tcombobox

I am using Delphi 11 Alexandria and am building an FMX project for release on Windows, iOS, and Android.

I am building a manual language translation system, to this end I have generated a mapping document that maps language text to components mapped using the component name.

My customer has insisted that no auto translation technology should be used.

My code works fine for everything accept `TComboBox` and `TListItem`?

When I set the text value for the `TListItem` on startup, it works. For instance, the design time values are in English, and if the save state determines the last used language was Deutschland then this function successfully changes the drop down text and header text of the `TComboBox` (very odd).

However, when I change the language after startup to change all the text, it does not change the drop down text, but does change the header text value.

I.e. I initially load the text in English, the save state loads in English, and then I change to Deutschland.

When I change to Deutschland, the header text in the ComboBox says "Bereich" but the drop down value says "Area". This is true for all of the drop down values, only the header text changes and not the drop down values?

Please note: I have added the `if` statement already `if cmp is TListBoxItem then` for an easy place to position any additional code to make it work.

```
procedure setLangTextVal(cmp: TComponent; text: string);
var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  Prop: TRttiProperty;
begin
  Prop := Ctx.GetType(cmp.ClassType).GetProperty('Text');
  if (Prop <> nil) and (Prop.Visibility in [mvPublic, mvPublished]) then
  begin
    if cmp is TListBoxItem then
      Prop.SetValue(cmp, text)
    else
      Prop.SetValue(cmp, text);
    Exit;
  end;

  Prop := Ctx.GetType(cmp.ClassType).GetProperty('Caption');
  if (Prop <> nil) and (Prop.Visibility in [mvPublic, mvPublished]) then
  begin
    Prop.SetValue(cmp, text);
    Exit;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug not in `TListBoxItem` but in `TComboBox` component. It has an optimization that prevents the list of items from being recreated every time the drop down is shown, except when an item is added or removed or the whole list is replaced through the `Items` property. Seems that simply changing the text of items doesn't trigger such drop down recreation.

A workaround is to disable this optimization by copying the source file `FMX.ListBox.pas` to your project folder and commenting out the `FItemsChanged` check at the `TCustomComboBox.InitPicker` procedure:

```
// if FItemsChanged then          <-- disable this check
// begin
  AListPicker.Values := Items;
  FItemsChanged := False;
// end;
```

Note this is based on Delphi 11.0 source files. Workaround may be different for previous/future versions of Delphi.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Alex.

You are right in what you say, it is indeed a bug in the Delphi source file. I have followed your suggestion and it now works. Thanks again for your input.

I have added this fix to the project source documentation as it will need testing and applying for every new Delphi version that comes out until it is fixed at source, I mention this as version 11.1 has just been released in the last few days.